# Read call log with exception on Viber calls

Tags: android, calllog, viber

I have code with reading call logs

```
    String[] strFields = {
        android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE, 
        android.provider.CallLog.Calls.TYPE,
        android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DURATION,
        android.provider.CallLog.Calls.NUMBER
        };
//READ CALL LOG     
Cursor callCursor = getContentResolver().query(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,strFields, null, null,android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE + " ASC");
startManagingCursor(callCursor);

int dateColumn = callCursor.getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE);
// type can be: Incoming, Outgoing or Missed
int typeColumn = callCursor.getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.TYPE);
// get duration of calls
int durationColumn = callCursor.getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DURATION);
// get number
int numberColumn = callCursor.getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
Calendar calendarCall = Calendar.getInstance();

if(callCursor.moveToFirst()){
do{         
    callDate = callCursor.getLong(dateColumn);
    callType = callCursor.getInt(typeColumn);   
    callDuration = callCursor.getInt(durationColumn);
    callNumber = callCursor.getString(numberColumn);

    switch(callType){
        case android.provider.CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE:

            break;
        case android.provider.CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE:

            break;
        case android.provider.CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE:                      

            break;
    }
}while(callCursor.moveToNext());    
}
```

Now problem is that Viber calls also included but I want to exclude them. Is there any way to exclude Viber calls from call log? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Depends on flags/columns. Did you find any flag, which could help you recognize Viber calls? If not, there is no way to get it from log.